# Any way to see if it's made of galvanized steel?

Tags: steel, cast-iron, galvanic-corrosion

Is there any easy way for me to see if something is made from regular steel or galvanized steel?

I'm having some galvanized steel bases installed at my apartment, but I want to make sure it's actual galvanized and not regular steel or steel with a coat of rustproof paint, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Post a clear, well-lit photo for us to look at. Some of us have seen enough electro-plated and hot-dipped metal to last a lifetime. Also, https://www.galvanizeit.org/education-and-resources/resources/technical-faq-dr-galv/how-to-tell-if-steel-has-been-galvanized.

Answer (score 1):

Galvanised steel has a distinctive "spangled" appearance. The crystalline structure of the Zinc is visible.

[image: Spangle]

There are two main types

- hot-dip galvanised
- electrogalvanised (electroplated zinc)

You can often tell if something has been hot-dip galvanised. It looks like a thicker coating is present. This is better.